# Listbox Insert Issue

Tags: vb.net, insert, vb.net-2010, listboxitems

I have researched this and can't find a reference anywhere to fix the issue.  I have created code to randomize about 20 items from a text document, and put them into a listbox on my form.  This is a legal document so, once randomized, it would be read back out into the text document, just in a different order.  Each item has a heading: REQUEST FOR ADMISSIONS NO. # (# being whatever number that question was in line).  I need those #'s to be in number order (1-20) despite the fact that the questions' order is scrambled. I kept working on that until I got it to insert that line, with an incremented number. But it is incrementing them backwards (see redacted example). [Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEKua.png) The culprit language is below. I think it is in there someplace:

```
      ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
            Try
                'do with listBox1.Items[i]
                For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    ListBox1.Items.Insert(i, "REQUEST FOR ADMISSION NO. " & nxtNum & vbCrLf)
                    nxtNum += 1
                Next
            Finally
                ListBox1.EndUpdate()
            End Try
```

Note: I was able to get it to work by flipping the list. Not elegant but it works.

```
            ListBox1.BeginUpdate()

            Try
                'do with listBox1.Items[i]

                For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

                    ListBox1.Items.Insert(i + 1, "REQUEST FOR ADMISSION NO. " & nxtNum & vbCrLf)
                    nxtNum += 1
                Next

            Finally
                ListBox1.EndUpdate()
            End Try

            nxtNum = 1

            Dim items() As Object = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).Reverse.ToArray
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items)
```

Comment: The problem might be in this line: "ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1" but if I reverse it, i.e. "0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step -1" it lists all the "REQUESTS FOR ADMISSION NO.  " [1-20] at the top of the listbox instead of before each line of the listbox as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided in your comment should work if not for one problem: the `Step -1`

The `For`-loop works like this when performing a new iteration:

```
New Value = Current Value + Step
```

Meaning, when you do:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step -1
```

you keep doing `Current Index + (-1)`, which is why they end up in the top; you keep going one step back.

The simple way to fix this is to change it to `Step 1` or just remove the `Step` part completely (as the default step is `1`, if omitted).

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    ...your code...
Next
```

---

**EDIT:**

I think I see your actual problem, I missed it... The descriptions are already there when you add these headers.

In this case you should be able to do:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step 2
    ...your code...
Next
```

Comment: I used the line you suggested - it gave me "REQUESTS FOR ADMISSION NO. 1, REQUESTS FOR ADMISSION NO. 2" etc down to 20.  Then it started my scrambled list of text items.  With the "Step - 1" It gives me "REQUESTS FOR ADMISSION No. 20 (next line) my scrambled text item 1, "REQUESTS FOR ADMISSION NO. 19 (next line) my scrambled text item 2, etc.  Which is what I need except for the numbers being 1-20 instead of 20-1. I can post the whole thing email it to you if you think that could help.

Comment: @TareyWolf : Well you never show us how you insert the other items, but why don't you just use my code and when you insert the "descriptions", loop by: `For i As Integer = 1 To ListBox1.Items.Count Step 2`.

Comment: @TareyWolf : No need to email, just edit your question and show me how you insert the other lines.

Comment: Ok, I figured out a way to do it though I know it isn't elegant it works:            ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
        Try
            For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

                ListBox1.Items.Insert(i + 1, "REQUEST FOR ADMISSION NO. " & nxtNum & vbCrLf)
                nxtNum += 1
            Next

        Finally
            ListBox1.EndUpdate()
        End Try

        nxtNum = 1

        Dim items() As Object = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of object).Reverse.ToArray
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items)

Comment: @TareyWolf : You do realize that my solution should do what you just showed me, but without all the additional reversing code? **EDIT:** Oh wait, I think I see your actual problem... I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: It's IT! Great solution. And I understand what you saw... escaped me too. Thanks VV.

Comment: @TareyWolf : I'm glad it worked! Please mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the green tick on it's left. :)